# Setup bluetooth interface in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to Android Studio. I had the code for bluetooth in mainactivity and it worked. But I am wondering how to rewrite that code in a fragemnt.java. I don't know what is going on but when I click into my blue_fragment, the app just crashes.
[image: code]
[image: code]
[image: code]
[image: code]
[image: code]
[image: code]
[image: code]

Comment: Have you tried to debug and tried to see wheres the problem ? I mean which line makes it crash?

Comment: Additionally, screenshots of code rarely help people to help you.  In order to run it to try help, I would have to manually type all of that into an IDE.

Comment: Please post your code in text format and not images. Besides that, what error do you get? We need more specifics to solve your question. Such a general question rarely gets answered. Specify your problem to a single small verifiable example that you would want to run in a fragment and ask that to the community. Don't expect them to do all the programming for you.